# How to hide pages of certain page types to the content editor

Tags: kentico

I want to hide my pages regarding Search functionality for the role of type content editor. How can I do this in Kentico 10?? Please help.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question more?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by hiding content type for a role in search functionality? You can deny read for a certain role on security tab in Pages application (for a page, not for a page type).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This may help:

https://docs.kentico.com/k10/configuring-kentico/setting-up-search-on-your-website/searching-according-to-page-permissions

If you set "Check Permissions" on the Smart Search results, it will not show pages the current user does not have access to.

Is that what you are looking for?